# Removing Duplicates while keeping last row between 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that populates a spreadsheet based on raw data in another spreadsheet.

The main sorting method for each row is by lane(Origin to destination). The results for each lane are further sorted by week. I'm needing to remove the duplicate weeks for each lane while keeping the last result.

The setup is similar to this: (Sorry for formatting)

```
  A         B
LANE A  WEEK 38
LANE A  WEEK 39
LANE A  WEEK 40
LANE A  WEEK 41
LANE A  WEEK 42
LANE A  WEEK 39
LANE A  WEEK 40
LANE A  WEEK 41
LANE A  WEEK 42
LANE A  WEEK 39
LANE B  WEEK 38
LANE B  WEEK 39
LANE B  WEEK 40
```

---

I found the following code that works nicely for a single lane

```
Dim Rng As Range, Dn As Range, n As Long
Dim Lst As Long, nRng As Range
Lst = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
For n = Lst To 1 Step -1
    If Not .Exists(Range("B" & n).Value) Then
        .Add Range("B" & n).Value, Nothing
    Else
        If nRng Is Nothing Then
            Set nRng = Range("B" & n)
        Else
            Set nRng = Union(nRng, Range("B" & n))
        End If
End If
Next n
If Not nRng Is Nothing Then nRng.EntireRow.Delete
End With
```

But as it only removes duplicates based on week, or column B, all of Lane B is removed.

EDIT:

End result should appear like this

```
 A         B
LANE A  WEEK 38
LANE A  WEEK 39
LANE A  WEEK 40
LANE A  WEEK 41
LANE A  WEEK 42


LANE B  WEEK 38
LANE B  WEEK 39
LANE B  WEEK 40
```

Here's a screenshot of an example set of data

https://imgur.com/a/MU6vB

At row 5 there's repeat data for the ATL6 lane. Afterwards comes CMH1. I need duplicate weeks within the same lane to be deleted, preserving the last update to the lane. As my code currently stands, it only looks at the week. So all of the ATL6 data is deleted and only the CMH1 is left.

For the ATL6 lane I need Rows 6-9 preserved, and 2-5 deleted as duplicates. This will need to apply in all situations, not just to these rows specifically.

Comment: To be clear. What is end result? (Please update original question). For example, in your sample date, Lane A will have two rows: Week 38 and Week 39 or only Week 39?

Comment: Update, to reiterate the update. Each update of the spreadsheet (which will be daily) will add 4 entries for each Lane. These follow weeks of the year, in 4 week spreads.

So the current sheet has Weeks 39-42 for each lane (around 15 or so). So the intended result would have 4 weeks for lane a, 4 weeks for lane b and so on.

This will be update daily for an indefinite period, so the number of weeks will grow over time

Comment: Why not just using the Sort function under the "Data" tab and then remove duplicates by column B? Record doing that with a macro

Comment: I need the most recent data to be preserved, so the last row of duplicate data should be the one to stay, which is what the code snippet I posted accomplished. However, I need what's in column A to be accounted for. I posted a screenshot in my original post that may illustrate what I'm needing better

Comment: Then store previous data in a separate sheet and keep current data in the primary sheet? Unfortunately what you're trying to accomplish sounds near impossible unless you're storing the consolidated data - after the duplicates are removed - on a different sheet **EDIT:** I shouldn't say impossible but an unnecessary task

Comment: Maldred,

My goal is to end with a sheet that is continuously updated more or less automatically. This is a process that will be ran with raw data every day, so to automate this process I need old data to be removed without user input and replace with the new data. I want to eliminated the need to save daily versions of the same spreadsheet and instead end up with all data over x period of time in one file.

Answer (score 0):

> **NOTE**
>
> I just realized this will *only* work if there are exactly two
>   duplicate sets. If there can be more than that, then let me know and I
>   will delete

I used the below code with this sample data (based on your sample data structure) and it worked. It takes advantage of Excel's built-in features but if you data set is *huge* performance may suffer.

**Before**

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveEarliestDupes()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws1

        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("D" & LastRow).FormulaArray = "=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A" & LastRow & "&B" & LastRow & ",$A$1:A" & LastRow - 1 & "&$B$1:$B$" & LastRow - 1 & ",0)),"""",""Remove"")"
        .Range("D" & LastRow).Copy

        With .Range(.Range("D2"), .Range("D" & LastRow - 1))
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
            .Calculate
        End With

        With .Range(.Range("D2"), .Range("D" & LastRow))
            .Copy
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .AutoFilter 1, "Remove"
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
            .ClearContents
        End With

        .AutoFilterMode = False

    End With

End Sub
```

**After**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott, but yes there is the potential for a relatively large number of duplicates, but performance isn't much of a concern. I did try and run that code, trimming down to 2 duplicates, but was getting an object error on .ClearContents and the contents of the sheet were deleted entirely

Comment: you can remove that line. it's not necessary.